# monitoring Node.js app connections

Tags: node.js, networking, performance-monitor, performance-measuring

I'd like to get real-time information on how many concurrent connections are opened by Node.JS client app, i.e. specific node process.

I've checked the following:

1. TypePerf/windows perf monitor - didn't find a way to monitor
   connections of specific process.
2. TcpView is nice - but no information on connections
3. AppMetrics - no information on connections just HTTP requests.

I'd prefer any solution that is open source and doesn't involve adding code to the existent Node.js App.

Update #1:
You can do it using TypePerf - by using process name "Node.js" but then you need to get the specific node PID. One workaround is to wrap the requested app using process fork - and passing the PID to perfmon.
But this is only for windows - what is the solution for *nix based clients.

Comment: Do you need continuous monitoring or just one-time stats gathering? If it's just one-time you can use tcpdump/ethereal. But I don't recommend it for continuous monitoring due to heavy cpu and i/o load

Comment: Continuous - I actually simply need some way to gather numbers.